# Mac OS replace multiline with one character using sed

Tags: regex, bash, macos, sed

I hope this is not duplicate, I read some questions, but I am still struggling to achieve this.

Let say i have this text:

```
{
  "root": {
    "2020-05": []
  }
}
{
  "root2": {
    "result": "error",
    "message": "You can't access this resource as it requires 'view' access for the website id = 206."
  }
}
```

How would I get the following result:

```
{
  "root": {
    "2020-05": []
  },
  "root2": {
    "result": "error",
    "message": "You can't access this resource as it requires 'view' access for the website id = 206."
  }
}
```

I need to replace

```
{
}
```

with just this

```
,
```

Or better I need to replace this

```
  }
}
{
```

with just this:

```
  },
```

What is the best way to achieve this using sed?

I am not sure about the regex part, I tried this `/^{}$/` and this `$}^${^`.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), it's just

```
jq -s add tmp.json
```

The `-s` option reads both objects in the stream into a single array, then the `add` filter combines the two objects into one.

A demonstration:

```
$ jq -s add <<EOF
> {
>   "root": {
>     "2020-05": []
>   }
> }
> {
>   "root2": {
>     "result": "error",
>     "message": "You can't access this resource as it requires 'view' access for the website id = 206."
>   }
> }
> EOF
{
  "root": {
    "2020-05": []
  },
  "root2": {
    "result": "error",
    "message": "You can't access this resource as it requires 'view' access for the website id = 206."
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I was thinking about jq, but the problem is, I already have this file which looks like the one in my example with a lot of json objects mashed together, so I suppose jq would not help and I need to use find and replace? I might be mistaken. I am not really familiar with jq, does the demonstration really work for this? I will go and try

Comment: This answer is not limited to combining two objects; `[a, b, c, ..., z] | add` is basically `a + b + c + ... z`.

Comment: Awesome, I did not know jq has this functionality, I tried this with EOF and it works perfectly, now the question is how to pass file which contains all this text? I tried this `echo | jq -s add < data.json` and it did not work. Probably a noob question, but it would really help me. Thanks

Comment: I am also trying this: `value=$(<data.json)
echo "$value"

echo | jq -s add <<EOF
$value
EOF` But I only get the first object. Is there a way to do this? Thanks"

Comment: OK, it is working now, I had a duplicate key, thank you very much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

`jq` can work but if you have the `perl` command you can also try:

```sh
perl -0777 -pe 's/}\n{/,/g' file.txt
```

See [argument docs](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/PERL/node161.html)

- `-0777` to read the whole file
- `pe` to evaluate what's in the quotes rather than a file, and loop it